# Detect If Variable Is A Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, detect, legacy

I cannot figure out a way to detect if a variable is a regex. But I also need to figure out if it is an object so I cannot use the `typeof(regex) === 'object'` and rely on it since it may since the if statement will execute it as if it was a regex. But I would like it to work in **legacy browsers** too. Any help will be most appreciated.

```
var regex= /^[a-z]+$/;

//...Some code that could alter the regex variable to become an object variable.



if (typeof(regex) === 'object') {
    console.log(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [instanceOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

```js
var regex= /^[a-z]+$/;

//...Some code that could alter the regex variable to become an object variable.



if (regex instanceof RegExp) {
    console.log(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this, they include :

```js
var regex= /^[a-z]+$/;

// constructor name, a string
// Doesn't work in IE
console.log(regex.constructor.name === "RegExp"); // true
// instanceof, a boolean
console.log(regex instanceof RegExp); // true
// constructor, a constructor
console.log(regex.constructor == RegExp); // true
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work in IE. Don't test for function names.

Comment: @Bergi That's why I mentioned the other methods.

Comment: But why mention it all? It just increases the chances that someone reading the answer picks up a bad practice (especially as it's mentioned first).

Comment: @Bergi I get it, I just added a comment about it.